# Can I expect Gnome 3.32 in the next point release of Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: gnome

I was looking for a PPA of Gnome 3.32 for Ubuntu 18.04.2 . But I couldn't find one . Currently Ubuntu 19.04 has Gnome 3.32 . Then Will Ubuntu 18.04.3 include Gnome 3.32 ?

Comment: Wait a year and get it or hopefully gnome 3.34 in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't be backported. After release, with a few exceptions, packages receive **only** high-priority bugfix patches and security patches.

The 'S' in LTS stands for *stability*. It doesn't refer to *system* stability - it refers to *workflow* stability. LTS releases were originally intended for long-term enterprise use with no workflow changes.

Folks who want newer software are welcome to use an Interim (6-month) release of Ubuntu. It's not a beta.